# How to implement subtitle in sap.ui.core.message.Message of semantic page?

Tags: sapui5

[Demo of sap.m.MessagePopover](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.MessagePopover/preview)

[Demo of sap.m.semantic.MessagesIndicator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.SemanticPage/code)

[API of MessageManager](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.message.MessageManager)

---

In [MessagesIndicator](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.semantic.MessagesIndicator) of semantic page, it use [sap.ui.core.message.Message](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.message.Message) to add message, but there is no `subtitle` property in `sap.ui.core.message.Message`.

In MessagePopover, it use [MessagePopoverItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessagePopoverItem) / [MessageItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessageItem) with `subtitle`.

So it seems if I want to use `subtitle`, my only choice is use `MessagePopover` with `MessageItem`.

I try to use `semantic:customFooterContent` to show message indicator:

```
    <semantic:customFooterContent>
        <OverflowToolbarButton icon="sap-icon://message-popup" text="Settings" press="onShowMessageIndicator"/>
    </semantic:customFooterContent>
```

But `semantic:customFooterContent` button is in the right footer of semantic page, and I need it in the left footer, just like `<semantic:messagesIndicator>`. Any idea? I don't want to change semantic page to m.page.

Comment: So, why can't you use standard message indicator button?  <semantic:messagesIndicator>
   <semantic:MessagesIndicator press="onMessagePopoverPress"/>
  </semantic:messagesIndicator>

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych, it seems `semantic:MessagesIndicator` must use with `sap.ui.core.message.Message` (as in demo), and `sap.ui.core.message.Message` do not have `subtitile` property.

Comment: There are "message", "description", "additionalText" properties, can you just use "additionalText" as your subtitile for "subtitle" property binding of the MessagePopoverItem ?

Comment: @AndriiNaumovych, yes, I have tried `additionalText` and `description`. `additionalText`  did not even show on the controller, and `description` need to nav to second-level page.

Comment: "additionalText did not even show on the controller" - what does it mean? Did you do the manual creation of the MessagePopover? If so, then show your coding

Comment: My Demo Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/LHuAJ9dTA9wdJg1NI2ZH?p=preview myAdditionalText did not show.

Comment: just add: subtitle: "{message>additionalText}" in the MessagePopoverItem template

Comment: OMG, stupid me! Thanks, it's working! Updated the demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/LHuAJ9dTA9wdJg1NI2ZH?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LHuAJ9dTA9wdJg1NI2ZH?p=preview)

Thanks to @AndriiNaumovych, I forgot to add `{message>additionalText}` in the `MessageItem` template.

(Changed [MessagePopoverItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.MessagePopoverItem) to `MessageItem`, because `MessagePopoverItem` is 
deprecated since version 1.46)

template:

```
        new MessagePopover({
            items: {
                path: "message>/",
                template: new MessageItem({
                    description: "{message>description}",
                    subtitle: "{message>additionalText}",
                    type: "{message>type}",
                    title: "{message>message}"
                })
            }
        });
```

Corresponding Message：

```
            new sap.ui.core.message.Message({
                additionalText: "myAdditionalText",
                description: "myDescription",
                message: "Something wrong happened",
                type: sap.ui.core.MessageType.Error,
                processor: oMessageProcessor
            })
```